# difference between perl dancer framework and apache2 http server

Tags: perl, dancer

I am new to the programming world and started with Perl couple of days back. I tried developing a web application using Perl. 
 Initially followed some tutorial and learned how to write simple CGI scripts using Perl and deployed it using Apache2 httpd server. After getting to know about the Perl Dancer it was much easier to develop a web application using the framework.
As both serve the same purpose I want to know weather Dancer is a replacement to the Apache httpd server or dancer internally uses apache to start a server. As dancer is just a web application framework how internally it is managing to handle the server request and responses.
Can anybody post a link where I can read and get to know about how the webserver works?

Answer (score 4):

Dancer has a [PSGI](http://plackperl.org/) interface.

PSGI is similar to CGI in that it allows a web server to communicate with the Perl application, but it is more efficient (it keeps the application running all the time so it doesn't need to load everything from scratch for each request) and has more features (e.g. the ability to use Plack middleware).

Dancer comes with a script to run a simple web server (which is not Apache) for development purposes.

It is expected that you'll use a more powerful web server (such as Apache HTTPD) in [production](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Dancer/lib/Dancer/Deployment.pod).

Comment: A link to Dancer::Deployment (or the one in D2) be helpful here.

Comment: [Running stand-alone behind a proxy / load balancer](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Dancer/lib/Dancer/Deployment.pod#Running-stand-alone-behind-a-proxy-load-balancer) has many advantages.